Selenium chrome-driver click problem in div element
HTML
<div class="hb-fzpaiS dEBb srjgzgk7zu4"><svg width="14" height="8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7.943 7.39c-.52.521-1.365.521-1.886 0l-4.78-4.78C.436 1.77 1.03.332 2.218.332h9.562c1.188 0 1.783 1.436.943 2.276L7.943 7.39Z" fill="#8C8C8C"></path></svg></div>

PYTHON
try:
            button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains (@class, 'hb-fzpaiS dEBb srjgzgk7zu4')]")))

            try:
                ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Failed to click button using ActionChains for {link}: {e}")

                try:
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Failed to click button using JavaScript for {link}: {e}")

                    try:
                        button.click()
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Failed to click button directly for {link}: {e}")
except Exception as e:
            print(f"Button not clickable or not found for {link}: {e}")

The web page I'm working on:
https://www.hepsiburada.com/magaza/a-34?tab=profile
I controlled the xpath. And Xpath is true. But When I was running the code block, I got GetHandleVerifier error. I tried many try-except block but I couldn't solve that.
Won't I be able to click on the div? How can I solve this problem?

You can try another scroll method. This worked for me:
driver.get('https://www.hepsiburada.com/magaza/a-34?tab=profile')
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Satıcı Bilgileri')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", button)
element.click()

Probably you will need to add wait until elements finish loading.
